# How do I use a common _ViewStart in areas?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, razor

In my "root" Views folder, I have a _ViewStart with the following code:

```
@Code
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.vbhtml"
End COde
```

In my Area/Public/Views folder, I have a copy of my _ViewStart from the root Views folder.

But when I run the code, I get this error:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'ASP._ViewStart_vbhtml' to type 'System.Web.WebPages.StartPage'.
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Can I use one `_ViewStart.vbhtml` for my areas too?

How can I use `_ViewStart.vbhtml` in Areas?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You need to copy the `~\Views\Web.config` file (or at least the following configuration elements) into your Area's View Web.Config:

```
<configSections>
  <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
    <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
  </sectionGroup>
</configSections>

<system.web.webPages.razor>
  <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
    <namespaces>
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    </namespaces>
  </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Comment: Wow thanks man! I would never have found this solution myself. Thank you for taking time to help me, you just saved me from pulling my last three hair out. :) Thanks again!!!

Comment: Glad I could help. We're looking into making this error message smarter so that it points out what the problem is.

Answer (score 35):

When I ran across this problem, I ran across this answer first but what I really wanted was on http://stevescodingblog.co.uk/asp-net-mvc-3rc-areas-viewstart/.

The gist of the issue is that _ViewStart.**html has a scope. It will apply to any views that are on the same level or in subfolders under it. Therefore, if you move it to the base directory (e.g. next to the Global.asax file), it will apply for all views under ~/Views/* **and** all views under ~/Areas/*/Views/*.

Similar to the accepted answer, you'll still have to copy the `<system.web.webPages.razor>` and `<sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor"..>` sections. Place them in your base web.config file (in the root of the project).

Here's a [more complete tutorial](http://www.develop.com/sharing-a-single-_viewstart-across-areas-in-aspnet-mvc).

For bonus points, you can override the _ViewStart.**html settings by creating a new file closer to the view in question (e.g. the file ~/Views/_ViewStart.cshtml will overwrite ~/_ViewStart.cshtml for all views in the ~/Views/ directory).

Comment: I'm having the same problem as MojoDK. As soon as I move the _ViewStart file to the root directory I receive this error. I have those two sections in each web.config including the root (under the runtime subsection - anywhere else and it won't let me debug). Could there be anything else to setting this up?

Comment: Just came around, nice answer, @havok I found that we have to put this appSettings as well: 
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
  </appSettings>

Comment: If you still get the "cast" error after doing all the above it can be caused by the _ViewStart.cshtml being cached.  Just open the file and do something to change the timestamp so it recompiles.  That fixed it for me.

Comment: Marking this down. This is an erroneous answer. This does not work. The _VewStart file cannot reside outside the Views folder.

Comment: Why can't it reside outside the Views folder? In what context does it not work? I just added a second source that has a more complete tutorial and links to an example project that shows it at work.

Comment: You say "like the accepted answer(...)", but actually the accepted answer describes the opposite procedure - copying the web.config sections *from* ~/views *to* /Area/SomeArea/Views. Took me a good couple of minutes to figure out I was doing it wrong.

Comment: [this tutorial](https://brockallen.com/2012/08/31/sharing-a-single-_viewstart-across-areas-in-asp-net-mvc/) explains the same answer in more details (one of the links in this answer is broken)

Answer (score 0):

I found that moving _ViewStart to the root and adding the system.web.webPages.razor section to the root web config worked, however I also needed to add a number of lines similar to this
  << add namespace="Ico.Logics.Web.Areas.Admin.Models" />>
to the copied section.