# Unable to cast object of type 'ASP._Page_Areas_Admin__ViewStart_cshtml' to type 'System.Web.WebPages.StartPage'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I created an area named "Admin".

In /Areas/Admin/Views/, I have _ViewStart.cshtml with this:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Areas/Admin/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

I'm getting the following error when I visit a page in /Admin/: **Unable to cast object of type 'ASP._Page_Areas_Admin__ViewStart_cshtml' to type 'System.Web.WebPages.StartPage'.**

I made the suggested changes from [How do I use a common _ViewStart in areas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4109205/how-do-i-use-a-common-viewstart-in-areas).

I have this in my web.config in the root, and the web.config at /Areas/Admin/Views/:

```
<configSections>
  <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
    <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
  </sectionGroup>
</configSections>

<system.web.webPages.razor>
  <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
    <namespaces>
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    </namespaces>
  </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>

<appSettings>
  <add key="webpages:Version" value="1.0.0.0"/>
  <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
  <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
  <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
</appSettings>
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

**EDIT:** Don't know if this helps, but if I delete the code in _ViewStart.cshtml so that it's empty, I'm able to view the pages in /Admin without getting an error.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`_ViewStart.cshtml` files can only be placed into a `Views` folder. The exception you are getting very strongly suggests that you have not placed the `_ViewStart.cshtml` inside the `~/Areas/Admin/Views/` folder (at the same level as the `web.config`).

Here's how a correct project structure should look like:

[image]

Comment: For me, `_ViewStart.cshtml` and `Web.config` are both at the same level. But I'm creating a pluggable architecture for MVC (putting controllers and views into a DLL, and dropping that DLL into `/Plugins` folder). I also get that exception. Any Idea @Darin?

Comment: @SaeedNeamati Try putting `@inherits System.Web.Mvc.ViewStartPage` in your _ViewStart.cshtml.

Comment: @ngm I upgraded MVC3 to the 4.5 framework and was facing this error.  Your inherits System.Web.Mvc.ViewStartPage worked for me.

Comment: Thank you.  I had a different but similar error which was the result of the same misplacement.