# ignore viewstart in asp.net mvc razor views?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

When I setup my site I didn't anticipate sections with completely different layouts, so I put the ViewStart page in the root of the Views folder. Reorganizing all the views is gonna be a huge pain.

Is there a way in specify in views to not inherit from the ViewStart page?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

First, take a look at this: [How do I use a common _ViewStart in areas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4109205/how-do-i-use-a-common-viewstart-in-areas).  This will show you how to use different _ViewStart files for different areas.

You can also override the Layout in each View if you'd like by simply setting the value in the page:

```
@{
   Layout = "~/Views/Shared/NewLayout.cshtml";
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is it possible to override with no layout?

Comment: Following up on Garrett's answer, the above comment of `Layout = ""` no longer works in later MVC releases and will generate a `Value cannot be null.` error.

However, weirdly enough, using `Layout = null;` will work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

No idea what pain you are talking about but that's the whole point of the `_ViewStart.cshtml` file: place one in some root view folder and all vies automatically inherit from it and AFAIK there is no way to tell some views not to use it.

Comment: Garrett's answer is correct afaik: you CAN override which layout to use for an individual view (although you rarely should do that, probably). Any particular reason why you think it isn't possible?

Comment: Apparently I didn't understand the OP's question correctly. Here's what he wrote: `Is there a way in specify in views to not inherit from the ViewStart page?`. And the answer to this is **NO** (as I already answered), you cannot exclude some views from not executing ViewStart. Actually what the OP was asking is how to change the Layout. Except that I didn't understand his question that way. I never said in my answer that you cannot change the Layout. All I said is that you cannot exclude some views from not executing ViewStart.

Comment: Ah, I see your point. I'm not sure if there is any inheritance from viewstart going on; afaik `_ViewStart` is `StartPage` which is a wrapper used by _pagestart to call methods on the actual page; but this might have been different in 2011. And I think you are correct that that cannot easily be changed, nor is it meant to.

Comment: If you edit your question, then I can remove my downvote. I suggest "... no way to tell some views not to execute ViewStart" or similar.

Comment: I do not intend to edit my answer at all. I answered what I understood from the question which apparently is wrong. There's already a correct answer to what the OP was asking.

Comment: this does not answer the question in any way