# MVC3 Single _ViewStart

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How to use one unique _viewstart.cshtml to all views and areas/views? I already move my _viewstart to root of the my site, but when I did this happened this error "Unable to cast object of type 'ASP._ViewStart_vbhtml' to type 'System.Web.WebPages.StartPage'.". My .configs are be inside /views folder. What's the problem?

Comment: What code do you have in your viewstart file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I use a common _ViewStart in areas?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4109205/how-do-i-use-a-common-viewstart-in-areas)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can't put the _ViewStart in the root of your site.  The ViewEngine looks for ViewStart in the Views folder.  So the only way to share the same ViewStart would be to use a hardlink and make the same file appear in both folders.

Answer (score 1):

> How to use one unique _viewstart.cshtml to all views and areas/views?

Not sure if you mean by that 1 file for all or 1 file per area.

If you want to use simply a single _ViewStart file, it must be placed in the Views folder.
That is where it is when starting a new MVC3 project.

If you want a file per area please read this post here:

[How do I specify different Layouts in the ASP.NET MVC 3 razor ViewStart file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161380/how-do-i-specify-different-layouts-in-the-asp-net-mvc-3-razor-viewstart-file)

> "Unable to cast object of type 'ASP._ViewStart_vbhtml' to type
>   'System.Web.WebPages.StartPage'."

This looks like you are mixing Razor with Webforms. If you are using a mixture of view engines, check your Global.asax that both view engines are added.

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    ...
    ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new WebFormViewEngine());
    ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new RazorViewEngine());
    ...
}
```

Try placing your _ViewStart file into the Views folder to start with as that is where it should be.

Answer (score 0):

For a file to be shared it shouldn't be in the root folder of the site.  It should be in the Views/Shared folder.

Comment: He's referring to sharing a file between Areas, not between views.  Areas have their own layout with their own Views folder.